# Silverlight Client Performance and Resource Usage

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm tempting to use Silverlight 3 tio create a LOB Application but I'm no quite comfortable into measuring client resource usage (CPU and RAM). Is there a way to measure exactly how much RAM /CPU a Silverlight App is using on the client ??? Are there any tools for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SilverlightSpy](http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=SilverlightSpy&lang=en-GB) measures this, at at high level. I am trying to find similiar tools at the moment and it seems that only Windbg and SOS willget right into the guts of your application :-(

Answer (score 2):

use the System.Windows.Analytics class to get the AverageProcessLoad and AverageProcessorLoad